# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/sdk/sdkmanager/DJISDKManager;

Tags: dji-sdk

Hi Im trying to run an application based on the code of the MediaManagerDemo. When i launch it, it breaks with this error:

I have every file as the tutorial code, i have

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/sdk/sdkmanager/DJISDKManager;
        at com.example.googlemapstrial.a.a(:56)
        at com.example.googlemapstrial.LoginActivity.s(:256)
        at com.example.googlemapstrial.LoginActivity.onResume(:204)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1377)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3712)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.googlemapstrial-K69B3-1Wb_UnUGqGyMFyLQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.googlemapstrial-K69B3-1Wb_UnUGqGyMFyLQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.googlemapstrial-K69B3-1Wb_UnUGqGyMFyLQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.googlemapstrial.a.a(:56) 
        at com.example.googlemapstrial.LoginActivity.s(:256) 
        at com.example.googlemapstrial.LoginActivity.onResume(:204) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1377) 
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7140) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3647) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3712) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Comment: You should try on real devices. I got the same your on emulator.
But you must be sure you are done [Official Guide](https://developer.dji.com/doc/mobile-sdk-tutorial/en/quick-start/user-project-caution.html)

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check...

(1) In the override to Application::attachBaseContext are you calling Helper.install(this)?

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

    Helper.install(this);
}
```

(2) Did you configure your Application override to be the active Application in the manifest?

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: yes, I did. I see the app stops after registering success, when it is supposed to open the Login pop-up, it closes.

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the SDK registration is successful and that the call to startConnectionToProduct as follows:

override fun onRegister(djiError: DJIError?) {
            if (djiError === DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                djiSdkInstance.startConnectionToProduct()